# how can i get returned value with double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i want to get a variable value with double quoted in javascript. i have an input field. i get the value from there but it is single quoted.

i try the below code already

```
let id=document.querySelector("#v_id");   //v_id is input field ID
let stringID= id.value;

var vObj = {id:stringID};
```

result is like that `{ id: '1'}`  see single quoted

i cannot use this value in JSON object.

i need a result like `{ id: "1"}`   see double quoted

i am expecting your precious answer

Comment: What is `v_id`? What value does it have? Where do you use that value in your JSON?

Comment: You see those quotes in the console? Just use `JSON.stringify()`, since those quotes are not part of the string. In JS both single and double quotes are usable to delimit a string, but they are not part of the string itself unless you manually do that. Compare `'123'` , `"123"`, `' "123" '` and `" '123' "`.

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: @AhuraMazda `vObj` is a JavaScript object, not a JSON. How do you make JSON of it? And what is the actual value that is entered in that input field? Does that contain the quotes already?

Comment: hi @Ivar. when i want to parse a JSON object i got this error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>

Comment: @AhuraMazda That is when you parse it, but in order to parse JSON, you will need the JSON string. How do you get that?

Comment: yes i see the point. i don't think JSON string different from Java Object. I stringify first, then parse it. thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify('123123'))
```

Comment: You also don't have to stringify each value individually, you can add values to your object, array, etc., then stringify the whole thing at the end.

Comment: Sure @blrzzzt this is just an example

Comment: Yeah just clarifying for the OP

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to convert it. Rather you can use bracket notation while creating the key

```
jsonObj[id.value] = 'someValue';
```